# Creating trigger in Postgresql not working

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a trigger in Postgresql, but the delimiter $$ isn't recongnized. I'have small problems with the syntax of Postgresql after moving from MySql, so excuse my if this is just a very basic question.

I tried this code

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name AFTER INSERT ON my_table FOR EACH ROW
$$
BEGIN
  //Execute statement
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But the error is

```sql
syntax error at or near "$$
BEGIN
  //Execute statement
END;
$$"
```

Comment: Read the docs [CREATE TRIGGER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) and [plpgsql trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html).  Nowhere do they show the trigger definition and the function body being declared in a single command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When developing triggers in PostgreSQL, you are not required to use $$ delimiters. Instead, specify the trigger independently and create your trigger logic using plpgsql functions and the $$ delimiter. Try the code given under, I updated your code:

```
-- Define your trigger
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
AFTER INSERT ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION your_function();

-- Define your PL/pgSQL function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION your_function() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  -- Your trigger logic here
  -- You can use NEW to access the newly inserted row

  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: The other way around, first create the function and then the trigger that calls this function. Otherwise you will get an error that the function doesn't exists.